# phpMyAdmin - "Please enter a valid length"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a table in phpMyAdmin, and I keep getting the same error no matter how I manipulate the SQL code. This is the preview SQL that phpMyAdmin generates

```
CREATE TABLE `puppies`.`animals` ( 
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `puppy_name` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `breed_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
    `description` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL , 
    `picture_url` VARCHAR(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `sold` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I've tried it with multiple variations of brackets and commas.

Comment: tested locally, works fine

Comment: It's working now too for some strange reason... this is a little worrisome but I guess I'll just stick with it for now. Thanks

Comment: It seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 22):

I have also faced the same issue and what I did was clicked on **Preview SQL** and copy the sql query and paste it in the SQL Run

Comment: my saver, vote up

Answer (score 11):

To those still experiencing this, and don't want to wait for it to randomly work again:

I just encountered this, and cannot find any explanation other than some bug.

I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`measurement_types` ( 
    `TypeID` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `Name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
    `Description` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`TypeID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Which produced the same "Please enter valid length" error

Tried a few times with different length values, but kept getting the same error.

--SOLUTION--

So I just created the table with a single column first, then altered it with the two other columns like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`measurement_types` ( 
    `TypeID` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`TypeID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And then:

```
ALTER TABLE `measurement_types` 
    ADD `Name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL AFTER `TypeID`, 
    ADD `Description` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL AFTER `Name`;
```

And that worked.

I also tried to delete the table and create it with the first SQL again, and this time it worked. Seems pretty random

Comment: I can confirm this "solution". I created the table without columns needing a length value (in my case a varchar column). Then I altered the table and added the same column and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue, seems to be a bug with VARCHAR fields. My solution was to make those fields INT, create the table, and then change them back to VARCHAR

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve it by restarting your mysql... It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug with varchar. If you change collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` it should fix the problem

[image]

Comment: Not a great answer because it doesn't tell you what implications changing the collation might have.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with PhpMyAdmin.
It needs 'Collation' value if column type is of varchar. You will encounter the error “Please enter a valid length” if the Collation field is empty for varchar. So basically both fields 'Size' and 'Collation' are mandatory and cannot be empty.

Please set Collation field with some value like 'utf8mb4_general_ci' to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue of "Please enter a valid length" by adding one by one column separately and by giving length to all the columns as the database needs to know how much memory it will consume.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely a problem with varchar fields but does not always happen.
You can still create your table by copying out the SQL query and executing the raw query.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official [docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-can-t-insert-new-rows-into-a-table-i-can-t-create-a-table-mysql-brings-up-a-sql-error), I think it is mandatory to give a specific length in later versions of phpMyAdmin.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved my “Please enter a valid length” by typing the length values for the data types that weren't of a dynamic memory allocation type. So therefore they obviously needed to know how much memory they could use for storage. Or by all means a valid length

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Varchar` you have to give a length. Otherwise, it will not save.

Comment: It goes without saying your answer is worthless, the problem is even if you enter a valid value you still get the error message. Understand the question

Comment: It's not worthless, it helped me. When I provided a length, the error went away and I was able to save my changes.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set a value for every varchar type.